# My Intel wireless adapter won't work on 802.11n mode on Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, router, 802.11n

I recently got a new wireless router (TP-Link TD-W8970) which is set to mixed b/g/n mode but I realised that my Windows 10 computer works only on b or g mode.

My wireless network adapter is an Intel Wifi Link 5100 AGN and as the name suggest it is n-mode compatible and has been working on n mode for quite a few years on a Netgear router (and Windows 7).

Other devices on the LAN will pick up the n mode just fine but not my computer.

From the adapter configuration I've Enabled N Mode:
[n mode enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56UXc.jpg)

But when I go to the "Wireless Mode" the n-mode value is missing from the list.

[list of wireless modes available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz73s.jpg)

My driver is provided by Microsoft (released in 2011 and supposedly up to date) and Intel themselves hasn't released a compatible driver for Windows 10 for now (or they might never will)

So basically I have an n-mode router and an n-mode adapter but I can only use g mode. Any suggestions?

P.S. Enabling n mode-only on my router would still be picked up as g-mode from my computer... I don't even know how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may be connecting in N mode already.

On my laptop, Task Manager says the connection type is 802.11g, but when I go to

Network Connections -> Wi-Fi (r-click) -> Status

the speed is 162Mbps. So I suspect Task Manager is reporting the wrong value.

The only setting I changed in the adaptor properties was Channel width for band 2.4, which I changed from 20MHz to Auto:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3OuA.png)